# Use Amazon’s SES to send email from PHP site

Tags: php, perl, amazon-web-services, sendmail, amazon-ses

I want to use Amazon’s SES (Simple Email Service) through the [Developer Scripts](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/Amazon-SES) for a PHP site, on an Ubuntu instance.

So far I'm successful in

1. verifying an email
   `./ses-verify-identity.pl -k ./aws-credentials -v email@example.com`
2. use `ses-send-email.pl` with the same credentials to send a test email

But when I try to bind them into the sendmail_path config in php.ini

```
sendmail_path = "/opt/third-party/amazon/ses/ses-send-email.pl -k /opt/third-party/amazon/ses/aws-credentials -f email@example.com -r"
```

All I get in the Apache error log is this:

```
Unknown option: oi
Usage:
    ses-send-email.pl [--help] [-e URL] [-k FILE] [--verbose] -s SUBJECT -f
    FROM_EMAIL [-c CC_EMAIL[,CC_EMAIL]...] [-b BCC_EMAIL[,BCC_EMAIL]...]
    TO_EMAIL[,TO_EMAIL]...

    ses-send-email.pl [--help] [-e URL] [-k FILE] [--verbose] -r [-f
    FROM_EMAIL] [TO_EMAIL[,TO_EMAIL]...]
```

Can anybody please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because PHPMailer [calls](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/source/browse/trunk/class.phpmailer.php#706) the [Postfix sendmail(1)](http://www.postfix.org/sendmail.1.html) with the option `-oi`:

> ```
>   -oi    When reading a message from standard  input,  don't
>          treat  a line with only a . character as the end of
>          input.
> ```

which is not handled by `ses-send-email.pl`.

One possible fix is to just [discard that option](https://github.com/mariusbutuc/ses-tools/commit/252a7f4f7892194067dd25cd79d8d66d9bd5ef8d).